# How to merge two arduino programs on Bluetooth and Fingerprint?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

Bluetooth and fingerprint are not responding simultaneously.

Bluetooth is used for controlling "Find me alarm" and Fingerprint is used to control the open and close motors.

The bluetooth is used to trigger the buzzer to make a buzzing sound. The fingerprint is used to control the four motors which is used to open and close the door

**How to merge these two programs?**

**Fingerprint :**

```
#include <FPS_GT511C3.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
FPS_GT511C3 fps(5, 4);
int buttonstate = 0;                             
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);          
  delay(100);
  fps.Open();
  fps.SetLED(true);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13,INPUT);
  pinMode(16,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(17,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(18,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(19,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  buttonstate=digitalRead(13);
  if (fps.IsPressFinger())
  {
    fps.CaptureFinger(false);
    int id = fps.Identify1_N();
    if (id <200)
    {
      Serial.print("Verified ID:");
      Serial.println(id);

        digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW); 
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(17,LOW);
  digitalWrite(18,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);

    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Finger not found");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Please press finger");
  }
  if(buttonstate == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(16,LOW);
  digitalWrite(17,LOW);
  digitalWrite(18,LOW);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

**Bluetooth :**

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BT(14,15);
String readdatta;
void setup() {
BT.begin(9600);
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

     char ch;
     while(ch!=0)
     {
      ch=BT.read();
      delay(100);

      if(ch == '1')
      {
        digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
       }
       else 
       {
        digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
       }

        }
       ch = ' ';
        }
```

Comment: Is one of your reads (bluetooth read or button read) blocking? If yes you need to manually create a second thread to handle both at the same time.

Comment: the key to merging programs is to understand both. simple as that. I'm not sure what kind of help you expect here.